# android change listview image source base on status

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor, android-viewbinder

trying to change a listView image item source depend on a field eg: if (status === 1) show red image else show green image. I tried a view binder with Simple Cursor Adapter, But that do nothing also not showing any error

```
private class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

        int viewId = view.getId();
        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(LoanDb.KEY_STATUS));
        ImageView noteTypeIcon = (ImageView) view;

        if(viewId == R.id.status_img) {

            switch (status) {
                case 0:
                    noteTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dot);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    noteTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_dot);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

this class located inside Main Activity as a child class, cant understand why this not working.

Comment: Well did you at least check if the method returns true?

Comment: yes, i checked, @Simas

Comment: what is the value of 'status' variable

Comment: before update 0, after update 1, in list most items status is 0, two of those status is 1. @Tanimreja